# How to Get Products with Same Records Using MAX in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have a Database like each product has Multiple same values, and i want to display the MAX same values product on top.

```
Example:

title         product             category

jack           nnn33                books
tom            nnn33                books
jay            vvv34                books
dex            lxxx3                books
rio            nnn33                books
james          nnn33                books
```

I want to display `nnn33` as max values record on top.

Check my Query below.

```
$query = mysqli_query($conn,
   "SELECT id,title,product,category FROM data WHERE category = 'Books' ORDER BY MAX(product) DESC LIMIT 10");
```

Comment: max of a string or a count?

Comment: get the max by count in an inner derived then an outer looper to show them first?

Comment: max of a string `nnn33` a product has same value multiple times should be on top

Comment: max of a string (if that even makes sense) would be `vvv34` no?

Comment: I want to display the product which has maximum same values as in my example is `nnn333` how to get this with my query?

Comment: so your expected results would have the 4 `nnn333` rows listed first with tie-breaks undefined?

Comment: Yeah the maximum values under 1 product should be on top and then the other product which has less values than the top one.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query?noredirect=1#comment391934_333952

Answer (score 2):

Max count items listed first, less counts follow.

Schema

```
create table myTable7
(   title varchar(100) not null,
    product varchar(100) not null,
    category varchar(100) not null
);
insert myTable7 values
('jack',           'nnn33',                'books'),
('tom',            'nnn33',                'books'),
('jay',            'vvv34',                'books'),
('dex',            'lxxx3',                'books'),
('rio',            'nnn33',                'books'),
('james',          'nnn33',                'books');
```

Query

```
select t7.title,t7.product,t7.category 
from 
(   select product,count(*) as theCount,@rownum:=@rownum+1 as theOrder 
    from mytable7 
    cross join (select @rownum:=0) xParams 
    group by product 
    order by theCount desc 
) d 
join mytable7 t7 
on t7.product=d.product 
order by d.theOrder,t7.title; 
+-------+---------+----------+
| title | product | category |
+-------+---------+----------+
| jack  | nnn33   | books    |
| james | nnn33   | books    |
| rio   | nnn33   | books    |
| tom   | nnn33   | books    |
| jay   | vvv34   | books    |
| dex   | lxxx3   | books    |
+-------+---------+----------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: The count in the select appears to be unnecessary

Comment: It is not in the final output. It is necessary based on op requirements

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: idk Straw. That's what I read into the last half hour of discussion